# How to Avoid Copying whole Values of a vector to the other container

Tags: c++, vector, reference, copy

How do I avoid copying whole values of vector `kws` into `req_kws` (the vector of vectors) below, while keeping two containers `kws` and `req_kws` in my code?

```
 vector<vector<string>> req_kws;
 for (string& request : requests) { 
    vector<string>& kws = req_kws.back(); //<-- define &kws to empty req_kws
    kws = split(kwsStr, ",");   //split is a parsing function upon string kwsStr
    req_kws.push_back(kws);
 }
```

I used in line number 3

```
vector<string>& kws = req_kws.back();
```

In this way, instead of storing all values of `kws` vector, only its reference is stored into `req_kws`.

But, I am getting a **segmentation fault** during the runtime.  Is there a way to fix it?

Thank you for your help.

Additional note;

Please note my constraint stated above that I need to keep both line number 4 (kws) and 5 (req_kws) intact, and want to use line number 3 of reference (&) or something similar to save the execution time from the same values being stored to both kws and req_kws. I have the other parts of the codes with the same problem, which are more complicate so that I can Not simply combine two lines of 4 and 5 into one.

Additional Question (Similar problem):

Thank you for your solution down below.  However, how about the following case, which is similar as above but more complicated.

```cpp
vector<unordered_map<string, string>> ads_kwsBids;
for (const auto& kwBid : kwsBids) {
    …
    unordered_map<string, string>& kwsBidsMap = ads_kwsBids.back(); //to prevent from being whole container copied
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < nsize; j++) {
        unsigned jdx = 2 * j;
        kwsBidsMap[splitedStr[jdx]] = splitedStr[jdx + 1];// constructing map kwsBidsMap
    }
    ads_kwsBids.push_back(kwsBidsMap);
}
```

In line number 4, that is,

```cpp
unordered_map<string, string>& kwsBidsMap = ads_kwsBids.back();
```

Because of the reference `&`, it yields the segmentation fault.  But, the reference is also the one that prevents `kwsBidMap` from being copied into `ads_kwsBids`.  Is there a way still to use the reference `&` on `kwsBidMap` and not get the segmentation fault?

Comment: As far as i can see in your code, req_kws is empty, calling "back" method on empty vector will produce undefined behavior.

Comment: You are right that the segmentation fault is caused by calling req_kws being empty.  However, is there a way to avoid the runtime failure?  Please note my contraint that I need to keep both line number 4 (kws) and 5 (req_kws) intact, and want to use line number 3 of reference (&) or something similar to save the execution time from the same values being stored to both kws and req_kws.

Answer (score 0):

In the code shown, `req_kws` is an empty vector.  Calling `back()` on an empty vector is Undefined Behavior. You either need to add an element to the vector first, or rewrite the code to not depend on having a value present.

From what I can gather you are trying to do, I think a simple

```
req_kws.push_back(split(request, ","));
```

should suffice.

Alternatively, you can rewrite the loop as

```
for (string& request : requests) { 
    req_kws.push_back(split(request, ","));
    vector<string>& kws = req_kws.back();
}
```

This will split the request string, store it in the `req_kws` vector, then create the `kws` reference to that newly added element.  Depending on what else you do with it, you may need to add `req_kws.reserve(requests.size());` before the for loop to avoid reallocations when adding to the vector.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I raised a similar yet slightly more complicated question by editing the above.  Would you take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of the solution to the problem.

```
vector<unordered_map<string, string>> ads_kwsBids;
for (const auto& kwBid : kwsBids) {
    …
    //Initialize the container with default value.
    ads_kwsBids.push_back(unordered_map<string, string>());
    //& used to prevent from being whole container copyed
    unordered_map<string, string>& kwsBidsMap = ads_kwsBids.back();
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < nsize; j++) {
        unsigned jdx = 2 * j;
        //Put kwsBids into a hash map
        kwsBidsMap[splitedStr[jdx]] = splitedStr[jdx + 1];// constructing map kwsBidsMap
    }
}
```